# How to ONLY return videos that can be played by my 3rd party application?

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-play-services

According to [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) the parameters `videoEmbeddable` and `videoSyndicated` set to true should only return videos that can be played outside of the standard YouTube site and apps.

Yet when I submit a query such as: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=15&q=cats&type=video&videoEmbeddable=true&videoSyndicated=true&key={my_api_key}` I get videos that return an error when trying to play them, such as "blocked from display".

I'm guessing that the content owner does allow the video to be played in certain 3rd party services and sites, but only whitelists the ones they choose. (Otherwise my query should exclude it.) My question is how can I return only videos that can be played in my custom application?

For a specific example, the video with an ID of `aB1psgIysBM` returned in the above query returns the blocked error when trying to play it within the same application that initiates the search using that URL.

**Edit:** Screen shot of the error: [image: video unavailabe in YouTube player fragment]

Also, I should add that this error is happening within an Android App using the official SDK. I realize that wasn't clear in the OP, but might be relevant.

Comment: aB1psgIysBM embeds/plays fine for me and there are no region restrictions. Can you add a screenshot of the error?

Comment: I did what @johnh10 requested. I have a new application, so I see no reason why Junkin Media would specifically block it (or even heard of if). Did you test it out within a custom application and not on the main site? I should add this is an Android App where I am experiencing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I believe that screenshot is for a separate content check (for lack of a better term) when the player is started, and I mostly see it for copyrighted music reasons. The YouTube API does NOT check or have that info (for whatever reason). As far as I know the content check is internal there is no way for us to do the content check ourselves. I hope they improve this someday. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: To clarify, is this 'content check' from the Android SDK? Is that what you mean by internal? Or does it just check any 3rd party application request? If so, can't they just add a filter for "Playable Outside of YouTube" or something pretty easily?

Comment: No, I think it's a generic check. I've encountered it just from embedding videos on a webpage. It's not integrated with the API for some reason.

Comment: So a generic check for what exactly? It must know that it's not the normal YouTube site or app because it plays in the site and app just fine. They say on the developer site that they check StackOverflow for these tags. I'm hoping one of them will look at it.

Comment: I don't know exactly but definitely copyright issues. YouTube hasn't specifically stated but perhaps they use 3rd parties like DailyMotion does: https://www.dailymotion.com/legal/contentprotection

Comment: Hmm, or maybe it's stated as syndicated? I just realized that syndicated means it can only be played with 3rd party apps that connect with YouTube for ad purpose driven revenue. I missed that part, and since there is no option for it to be false (only accepts 'any' or 'true') I assume that means it's just syndicated by the content owner. Kinda a bummer not to include a false option there. Like what's the point?

Comment: I mean I get that they aren't the same, but how can I test it to verify it's checking for copyright and not syndication?

Comment: As far as I know the content check is internal there is no way for us to do the content check ourselves.